# Cannot resolve method 'run(Class, String[])'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image]

Here's the code in the image

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to create a springboot project for the first time. I just installed the IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version 3month free trial when the IntelliJ Community Version already exists in my computer. I changed the path of the root to the bin folder of Ultimate version. But this error comes.

Previously I had and error in pom.xml also and it solved when applying the following code block.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </plugin>
```

I hope someone's help to solve this problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Forgive me if I did a mistake. I will edit the question.

Comment: You'll need to set up a Java SDK for your project before anything will work in IntelliJ IDEA. Click the "Setup SDK" link in the upper right.